# PHPUnit Selenium2 not returning text

Tags: php, selenium, selenium-webdriver, phpunit

I am trying to get the `text` value from an element and I tried lots of variation. nothing worked.. this is my latest attempt:

```
    $totalFlightPrice = $row->elements($row->using('css selector')->value('span[class="totalPriceToBook"]'));
    echo 'counted: '.count($totalFlightPrice)."\n";
    foreach ($totalFlightPrice as $tp) {
        echo 'text: '.$tp->text()."\n";
    }
```

when I'm using var_dump on totalFlightPrice I am receving the Object, which means its able to find the div.
but when im using the text function nothing is returned.

this is my span element:

```
<span class="totalPriceToBook">382€</span>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using getText() method http://docs.tadiavo.com/phpunit/www.phpunit.de/pocket_guide/3.1/en/selenium.html takes xpath of an element as a parameter.

```
$this->getText("xpath=//div/span[@class='totalFlightPrice");
```